# Azure Apps Custom Authentication SigningKey

Tags: c#, azure, jwt, azure-mobile-services

I am following the documentation on:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk/ to build custom authentication. I am wondering what is the SginingKey format in the following code snippets:

```
app.UseAppServiceAuthentication(new AppServiceAuthenticationOptions()
{
    // Here
    SigningKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["authSigningKey"],
    ValidAudiences = new[] { ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["authAudience"] },
    ValidIssuers = new[] { ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["authIssuer"] },
    TokenHandler = config.GetAppServiceTokenHandler()
});
```

And:

```
JwtSecurityToken token = AppServiceLoginHandler.CreateToken(
new Claim[] { new 
Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, assertion["username"]) },
                // And here
                mySigningKey,
                myAppURL,
                myAppURL,
                TimeSpan.FromHours(24));
```

Is it a, Base64String? Normal String? I noticed in some scattered examples it is sometimes a byte array converted into Base64String.

**What is the right string format and how can I generate a test value?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signing key is a hex encoded string. You can use any value for test purposes - provided that the key used to generate JWT tokens is the same as the key used to validate them.

You can retrieve the value used in an Azure Web or Mobile App by opening a browser to https://your_app_name.scm.azurewebsites.net/Env.cshtml#envVariables and finding the WEBSITE_AUTH_SIGNING_KEY value.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Your answer contradicts with the answer above which says you can specify Base64. How sure are you?

Comment: I checked with the engineer - the value can be either hex encoded or base64. The value assigned automatically by Azure is a hex encoded string.

Answer (score 0):

It's whatever you are using to sign the key.  If you are specifying a Base64 string (which is normal), then it's that.  Note that the `UseAppServiceAuthentication` section is only used when you are running the service locally.  It is handled automatically for you when running within Azure App Service.

Comment: So, if I specify Base64, then I could just assign it in both of my examples without any further conversion from one type to the other?